# Parsing mmaped file with strtok?

Tags: c, string, parsing, mmap, strtok

Here is my problem: I want to map the file "filename.txt", which basically consists of two pairs of strings per line:

```
"string1 string2
 string3 string4
 string5 string6..."
```

and then I wanted to separate the different strings using strtok.

So I map the file like this:

```
// open file
if ((fdsrc = open("filename.txt", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "src open error");
        exit(1);
    }

// get the size of the file
if (fstat(fdsrc, &statbuf) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fstat error");
    exit(1);
}

// mmap the file
if ((src = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fdsrc, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap src");
    exit(1);
}
```

When I run the line

```
printf("src: %s \n", src);
```

it prints the content of the file correctly!

But when I try to separate the words

```
char* token;
token = strtok(src, " \n");
while (token != NULL) {
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
}
```

the output is Segmentation Fault.
Why can't I use the StrTok then?

Comment: strtok is *DESTRUCTIVE* - it writes to the string as it tokenizes it.  SOLUTIONS: 1) Copy each string to a local buffer before trying "strtok()", or 2) Open the mapping Read/Write (instead of read-only).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the string it operates on.  Assuming you don't want to change the file contents, you need to change your `mmap()` options.

You are opening and mapping the file read-only:

```
if ((fdsrc = open("filename.txt", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
...
if ((src = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fdsrc, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1) {
...
```

Map the file with `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` and `MAP_PRIVATE`:

```
src = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fdsrc, 0);
if (src == (caddr_t) -1) {
```

You might need to open the file with `O_RDWR` instead of `O_RDONLY`

**BEWARE THOUGH:**

If the file size exactly matches a multiple of the page size used for the mapping, the file will not be a NUL-terminated string and you will likely get a SIGSEGV when `strtok()` attempts to read past the end of the mapping.

In that case, you can `mmap()` a zero-filled page immediately following the file's mapping.

Comment: This looks like bad advice.  The file will be modified, probably not what the OP intends.

Comment: @chqrlie Wrong.  Per http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html:  **MAP_PRIVATE**
              *Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the
              mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same
              file, **and are not carried through to the underlying file**. ...*

Comment: My bad, you are correct. But I insist it is still a contorted and way to parse a text file.  Specifically, `strtok()` should not be used because the buffer may not be `'\0'` terminated before the end of the mapping, hence invoking undefined behavior, for instance if the file length is an exact multiple of the page size.

Comment: @chqrlie - Agreed, it's contorted.  But that's how the OP seems to want to solve his problem.  I'll add the part about the size of the file exactly matching the page size.

Comment: What you are suggesting is not guaranteed to work: The BSD man page for `mmap` says: *If offset or len is not a multiple of the pagesize, the mapped region **may** extend past the specified range.  Any extension beyond the end of the mapped object will be zero-filled.*  So it may work or not work.  On systems that have fine grained control for memory protection, the mmapped area may be byte based.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks.  There are definitely platform-dependent aspects to modifying `mmap()`'d files with string-based functions such as `strtok()`.  For example, try determining the page size on Solaris, expecially on SPARC hardware, where there are 5 possible page sizes from 8kB up to 2GB.

Comment: `sysconf()` should be used to get the pagesize.  It is needed if you pass a non-zero offset, which must be a multiple of pagesize.  `mmap` to parse input files is not for the faint of heart and definitely not advisable for beginners.  It is not a generic solution as it cannot be used for pipes or console input.  It is usually overkill as a classic scanner is fast enough in most cases.

Comment: @chqrlie - The problem with `sysconf()` is that it returns **a** pagesize.  Solaris and Linux both now support different page sizes at the same time, even in the same process address space.  See the **MAP_HUGE_2MB** and **MAP_HUGE_1GB** flags:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html  So "the" page size isn't sufficient.

Comment: Good point.  *not for the faint of heart* was an understatement.

Answer (score 3):

Your file is mapped read only with `PROT_READ`. But `strtok()` modifies its first argument, `src`, and gets a segmentation fault. You would need to either make a writable copy before you use `strtok`, or switch to a mechanism that only reads its input. In my opinion, changing the protection of that buffer to `PROT_RW` seems odd, especially if you intend to use the unmodified contents of that file elsewhere in your program.

For an alternative, I'd recommend using `strstr()` (or an alternative implementation that doesn't require nul-byte termination) to locate the end-of-line substring, and then starting your next search where you found the last occurrence, plus the length of your substring. See the note below on nul-byte termination. A simplified example:

```
  const char *delim = "\n";                                                                                                                          
  const char *start = src;                                                                                                                           
  const char *end = NULL;                                                                                                                            
  const int srclen = statbuf.st_size;                                                                                                                
  const int delim_length = strlen(delim);                                                                                                            

  while (start && start < (src + srclen)) {                                                                                                          
    end = strstr(start, delim);                                                                                                                      

    if (NULL == end) {  
      // use of %.* to print at most X chars from string.                                                                                                                             
      printf("Token: %.*s\n", (int) (src + srclen - start), start);                                                                                 
      break;                                                                                                                                         
    } else {                                                                                                                                         
      printf("Token: %.*s\n", (int) (end - start), start);                                                                                           
      start = end + delim_length;                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                
  }
```

**mmap region may not end in a nul byte  (as suggested by comment)**

`strstr()` works on null-terminated strings. Your mmapped region may not end with a null byte. It is likely that the kernel erases the remainder of the last mmapped memory page (past the end-of-file) with `\0`s to avoid data leaks between processes, but if your file length is exactly a multiple of the page-size, you'll have trouble with using `strstr()` -- there won't be a nul byte to get your back.

You could roll out your own little string finder `strnstr()`. Or force another null page to be stamped at the end.

Comment: You should not use `strstr` because the `mmap`ped buffer is not necessarily `'\0'` terminated.

Comment: thanks @chqrlie. you are correct. this sent me in a little test spiral. `read()` calls are allowed when `seek()`ing past EOF (returns 0B), so I wondered what asking mmap a region bigger than the file would yield. What I ended up finding (on linux at least) was that the last buffer page containing file data will be filled with zeroes if the file size isn't a multiple of the page size. Reading a 10B file into an 8MB mmap buffer (w/ 4K page) for instance will give you zeroes for indices 10 to 4095, but if you read anything between index 4096 and 8MB, you'll get a bus error (SIGBUS).

Answer (score 2):

`strtok()` modifies the `char` array to which you pass a pointer.

You `mmap` the file in read only mode, so you get a violation when `strtok` tried to modify the memory.

It would be a bad idea to `mmap` the file in read+write mode, the file would be modified and probably corrupted.

`strtok` is inappropriate for you purpose, write your own matching function that does not modify its argument array and returns offsets and lengths.

Also be aware that the `mmap`ped memory should not be accessed beyond the size of the file and is not necessarily `'\0'` terminated, hence you should not use string functions to search into it (`strchr`, `strstr`, `strlen`...) nor copy from it (`strcpy`).